# maven-failsafe-plugin listener not working with new JDK

Tags: java, maven, junit, appium, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have Appium tests, written in Java.
The tests run with Maven, using maven-failsafe-plugin 2.19.1, junit 4.8.2.

We're in the process of upgrading from jdk 1.8 to 11.0, and for some reason our `RunListener` isn't called anymore when using the new JDK.

My listener is pretty straightforward, looks something like this:

```
@RunListener.ThreadSafe
public class ReportingListener extends RunListener {
    @Override
    public void testRunStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
        super.testRunStarted(description);
        // do stuff...
    }
    
    @Override
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
        super.testFailure(failure);
        // do stuff...
    }
    
    @Override
    public void testIgnored(Description description) throws Exception {
        super.testIgnored(description);
        // do stuff...
    }
    
    @Override
    public void testAssumptionFailure(Failure failure) {
        super.testAssumptionFailure(failure);
        // do stuff...
    }
    
    @Override
    public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
        super.testFinished(description);
        // do stuff...  
    }

    @Override
    public void testRunFinished(Result nativeResults) throws Exception {
        super.testRunFinished(nativeResults);
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

The test run is configured like this: (in the pom.xml)

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <runTestsInParallel>${shouldRunParallel}</runTestsInParallel>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
        <execution>
            <id>test-run</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skipITs>${skipParallel}</skipITs>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/AA_*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/ZZ_*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <runTestsInParallel>false</runTestsInParallel>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>my.package.core.reporting.ReportingListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I couldn't find in Google anywhere that would explain this weird behavior, why would updating the JDK version break this feature?

Thanks.

Comment: First: Why are you using such an old version of JUnit (12 years old) ? (currently 4.13.2 https://search.maven.org/artifact/junit/junit) furthermore why using such old version of maven-failsafe-plugin (2.19.1 from 2015?) https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin. Also why using a listener in Junit 4 ? What is the purpose of that listener ? Why is the configuration contradicting itself...and the real question is: What means: `does not work` ? Give more information ...also some example tests/log output/maven version  etc..

Comment: By "not working" I meant the listener class isn't being called at all, it's like failsafe-plugin straight up ignores it for some reason. The purpose of the listener is to aggregate the test run results and write out some JSON files with summaries, for internal company reporting purposes. As for the versions being old - it's a huge project in a huge company, I can't just go an update dependencies...

Comment: Can you create an example project on github or alike ..to demonstrate the problems ...